# SIP/Asterisk: No domain name in FROM uri's header

Tags: asterisk, sip, freepbx

I am using FreePBX. While trying to login I am getting

```
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:83.245.241.98:34479 --->
SUBSCRIBE sip:5666@0.0.0.0;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 83.245.241.98:34479;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---e49547006939fc6c
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:5666@83.245.241.98:34479>
To: <sip:5666@0.0.0.0>
From: <sip:5666@>;tag=b9144d7a
Call-ID: wDigYoT9KjWu52sD4lFLTQ..
CSeq: 1 SUBSCRIBE
Expires: 3600
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: replaces, norefersub, extended-refer, timer, outbound, path, X-cisco-serviceuri
User-Agent: Z 3.9.32144 r32121
Event: message-summary
Allow-Events: presence, kpml
Content-Length: 0


<------------->
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: --- (15 headers 0 lines) ---
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Sending to 83.245.241.98:34479 (NAT)
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Creating new subscription
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Sending to 83.245.241.98:34479 (NAT)
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] sip/route.c: sip_route_dump: route/path hop: <sip:5666@83.245.241.98:34479>
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] ERROR[5545] chan_sip.c: Empty domain name in FROM header
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] NOTICE[5545] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:5666@>;tag=b9144d7a for SUBSCRIBE
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c:
<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 83.245.241.98:34479 --->
SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 83.245.241.98:34479;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---e49547006939fc6c;received=83.245.241.98;rport=34479
From: <sip:5666@>;tag=b9144d7a
To: <sip:5666@0.0.0.0>;tag=as03163a1a
Call-ID: wDigYoT9KjWu52sD4lFLTQ..
CSeq: 1 SUBSCRIBE
Server: FPBX-13.0.192.16(14.6.0)
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
[2017-09-12 12:09:03] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Really destroying SIP dialog 'wDigYoT9KjWu52sD4lFLTQ..' Method: SUBSCRIBE
```

On registering device it shows

```
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: 19:27:20.484   pjsua_core.c  .TX 645 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=54664 (tdta0x78c4c36c) to UDP 35.162.177.84:5060:
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: REGISTER sip:mydomain.com SIP/2.0
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.43.224:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj8a5802d4-1b9a-49f0-b3c1-b38a23e51299
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: Max-Forwards: 70
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: From: <sip:5666@mydomain.com>;tag=6390922e-056e-4421-a55f-13e76117593e
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: To: <sip:5666@mydomain.com>
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: Call-ID: 63b10417-58a5-44b5-83a3-1fc1febab86b
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: CSeq: 54664 REGISTER
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.6-svn
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: Contact: <sip:5666@192.168.43.224:6000;ob>
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: Expires: 300
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: Content-Length:  0
09-12 19:27:20.483 I/System.out: --end msg--
09-12 19:27:20.973 I/System.out: 19:27:20.981    pjsua_acc.c  ...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
09-12 19:27:20.973 I/System.out: 19:27:20.982    pjsua_acc.c  ...Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 0 in 297 seconds..
```

From device logs I see the domain name, but in error message it's empty. Why can it be so?

Registering device is Android, but when I try desktop Zoiper, the error is the same.

I can show any settings from FreePBX, but I don't know which ones to show. If you feel that you need some of them to help me, feel free to request, and I'll post them as update

**UPD**

Here are new log portion

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:83.245.241.98:34479 --->
REGISTER sip:0.0.0.0;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 83.245.241.98:34479;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---42d9af389a67cbe0
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:5666@83.245.241.98:34479;transport=UDP;rinstance=5ffbd839a509bdb2>;expires=0
To: <sip:5666@0.0.0.0>
From: <sip:5666@>;tag=99170228
Call-ID: mH4uHh2CI96Kfv9h6c1uHA..
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: replaces, norefersub, extended-refer, timer, outbound, path, X-cisco-serviceuri
User-Agent: Z 3.9.32144 r32121
Allow-Events: presence, kpml
Content-Length: 0


<------------->
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: --- (13 headers 0 lines) ---
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Sending to 83.245.241.98:34479 (NAT)
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c:
<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 83.245.241.98:34479 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 83.245.241.98:34479;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---42d9af389a67cbe0;received=83.245.241.98;rport=34479
From: <sip:5666@>;tag=99170228
To: <sip:5666@0.0.0.0>;tag=as718e8353
Call-ID: mH4uHh2CI96Kfv9h6c1uHA..
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
Server: FPBX-13.0.192.16(14.6.0)
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Expires: 0
Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 17:30:02 GMT
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog 'mH4uHh2CI96Kfv9h6c1uHA..' in 32000 ms (Method: REGISTER)
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:83.245.241.98:34479 --->
SUBSCRIBE sip:5666@0.0.0.0;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 83.245.241.98:34479;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---5d5c7b4cc8b27f1c
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:5666@83.245.241.98:34479;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:5666@0.0.0.0>
From: <sip:5666@>;tag=134c433d
Call-ID: 9Fo9pY2cNfL9I3ZcT_rE1w..
CSeq: 1 SUBSCRIBE
Expires: 3600
Accept: application/simple-message-summary
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: replaces, norefersub, extended-refer, timer, outbound, path, X-cisco-serviceuri
User-Agent: Z 3.9.32144 r32121
Event: message-summary
Allow-Events: presence, kpml
Content-Length: 0


<------------->
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: --- (16 headers 0 lines) ---
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Sending to 83.245.241.98:34479 (NAT)
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Creating new subscription
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] chan_sip.c: Sending to 83.245.241.98:34479 (NAT)
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] VERBOSE[5545] sip/route.c: sip_route_dump: route/path hop: <sip:5666@83.245.241.98:34479;transport=UDP>
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] ERROR[5545] chan_sip.c: Empty domain name in FROM header
[2017-09-12 13:30:02] NOTICE[5545] chan_sip.c: Failed to authenticate device <sip:5666@>;tag=134c433d for SUBSCRIBE
```

**UPD2**

I changed client's wifi to another and it worked. Then I changed it back and it did not work again. The local subnet of wifi in which it worked has the same subnet address and mask (although it's another subnet), can it be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Your REGISTER message looks valid - and contains correct domain name set in proper places. But it has no Authenticatioon header.

According to the logs registration failed due to timeout - but I see no response 408 - so probably timeout is on the client. Nobody responded to the REGISTER.

So you need to find a reason for failure to handle REGISTER on the server, or to transfer request to the Server, or to deliver response to the client.

Even if you post SUBSCRIBE message first - I suppose the SUBSCRIBE should follow the REGISTER. But since registration was not finished properly - some variables in the client were not initialized. And client created invalid SUBSCRIBE request. Domain in request URI and in the to is 0.0.0.0 in the From is missing.

So this message probaby will never be delivered properly. And even if it is delivered - will fail the parsing. So it is rejected. This message should never be sent - it is bug of the client. It should check the registration state before trying to subscribe to the message-summary event.

Comment: The thing is the client is not mine - it's Zoiper client. It wasn't updated and used to work with an old version of the very server (which I failed to backup). I will investigate if it's possible to be client error, but it seems strange for me if it is. Do you have any other ideas how this can be solved on server side?

Comment: 1st check that REGISTER message arrived to the server, for example by running tcpdump on the server. 2nd check that Server responded to it. Currently I do not know what could be a reason for failed registration. I suppose it is possible that problem with SUBSCRIBE will not happen when registration is successful.

Comment: I have added new log portion, there REGISTER is present, please see updated question. No response was made from server

Comment: Now your REGISTER has same problems as SUBSCRIBE - and it is accepted for some reason instead of being rejected. But it is CSeq 3 - so it is not first iteration. 
Could you reset the client and collect logs starting with first REGISTER? Seems to me after failed registration Client has reset the domain variable and starts generating invalid requests. So nothing proper could be done by it after this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your network on sip.conf?

Example:

**[general]**

**externip = 83.245.241.98**

**localnet=192.168.43.0/255.255.255.0**

Comment: Yes externip is set. localnet is set through GUI, but I'm pretty sure that FreePBX developers took care of that (AFAIK I cannot change conf files manually when using FreePBX, can I?)

Comment: Yes you can - /etc/asterisk/sip_nat.conf

Comment: I checked again - those settings are done in conf files already